# put data with mongodb in db already exist

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo

I come with you because it's been three days I try to put data I grab with scrapy in my db, but it's not working.

I try to fill the tab land in my db ( the name is mtdbdd), who have inside, with an auto-increment id (I think maybe it's the cause of my problem but I don't really know). So in my item in scrapy, I don't have a file name id, maybe I should have.

I try something like that:

```
def put(self, item):
    MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://root:root@127.0.0.1:8889'

    client = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
    db = client.mtdbdd
    coll = db.land

    try:
        result = coll.insert_one(item)
    except coll.errors.OperationFailure as e:
        print e.code
        print e.details
```

and I have the error :

```
KeyError: 'Annonce does not support field: _id'
```

(Annonce is the name of my item)

If someone can help me, it would be awesome!
thanks guys!

edit: my item:

```
class Annonce(Item):
    url = Field()
    title = Field()
    price = Field()
    surface = Field()
    description = Field()
    city = Field()
    zipcode = Field()
    date = Field()
    img = Field()
    scrap = Field()
    url_title = Field()
    full_address = Field()
    viability = Field()
    gas = Field()
    visiblePhone = Field()
    isolate = Field()
    slope = Field()
    beingChanged = Field()
    toRenew = Field()
    csvFile = Field()
    views = Field()
    deleted = Field()
```

Comment: what is your `item`.?

Comment: i edit and i add my item

Answer (score 0):

Convert `item` to dict, before you insert it in database, i.e. change

```
result = coll.insert_one(item)
```

to

```
result = coll.insert_one(dict(item))
```

As a sidenote, MongoDB does not have anything like *tab* and does not naturally support *auto-increment*.

Comment: I try already but i have the error:
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: Got opcode 2628 but expected 1

Comment: @bastienlequéré This error doesn't have anything to do with your question, for sure. Your former error message originates in Scrapy which means before even touching MongoDB. `ServerSelectionTimeoutError` originates in MongoDB, i.e. original problem got fixed. To overcome the later, try to pass `connect=False` to `MongoClient` constructor.